# how to get parameters from url in zend framework 1?

Tags: php, zend-framework, parameters, get

I want to get 2 parameters from a URL and use them in my action, here is my code:

URL: `mysite.com/myaction/1/string`

myaction:

```
public function myactionAction($id, $string)
{

$params = $this->_getAllParams();
        print_r($params);
}
```

I am newbie to ZF, so how I can get these 2 parameters?

Comment: Try this: `$value = $this->getRequest()->getParam('your key');` in your action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write param names in url and then get your param value in following way:

```
$param1 = $this->getRequest()->getParam('param1');

$param2 = $this->getRequest()->getParam('param2');
```

URL should look like this:

```
http://example.com/mycontroller/myaction/param1/value1/param2/value2
```

And if you want to get param values from below url:

```
http://example.com/myaction/value1/value2
```

then go for Zend Route. Try below code:

```
routes.activate.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
routes.activate.route = "activate/:param1/:param2"
routes.activate.defaults.module = "core"
routes.activate.defaults.controller = "newsletter"
routes.activate.defaults.action = "activate"
```

Comment: thank you, what should be the routing for this action to make it accepts parameters?

Comment: Are you creating your routes in .ini file?

Comment: yes, find below the action that i want it to get parameters:
`;activate

routes.activate.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"

routes.activate.route = "activate"
routes.activate.defaults.controller = "newsletter"
routes.activate.defaults.action = "activate"`